# Negative curves on surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is there a complex smooth projective surface $S$ that contains infinitely many negative curves $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ with strictly increasing geometric genus $g(C_i)<g(C_{i+1})$?

Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: Please correct me if I am misunderstanding your question, but would a proof that no such examples exist show, combined with [your proof of the "weak bounded negativity conjecture"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09463) that the (usual) bounded negativity conjecture is true?

Comment: Apologies for the multiple comments, but [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/67008/33088) seems to say that there exists a hyperelliptic curve $C$ whose self-product $C \times C$ has infinitely many curves with negative self-intersection and unbounded genus.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama   Yes exactly.    Thank you for your MO answers.   That means somehow the BNC should not be that easy.